# What are the variables in this block of code for this button?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone tell me the  different variables in this block of code, if it is also possible know details of the process that would also be great:

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click
    Dim points As Integer = 0
    If IsNumeric(Label68.Text) Then
        points = CInt(Label68.Text)
    End If

    If points = 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Draw!"
    ElseIf points > 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Team 1!"
    ElseIf points < 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Team 2!"
    End If
    'This is a button that shows the scorer the outcome of the cricket match and it is dependent on the totals of both the batting scores, the validation is shown above
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the variables in this block of code for a Login button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586541/what-are-the-variables-in-this-block-of-code-for-a-login-button)

Comment: this is not a tutorial service: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20586541/1070452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I will explain each line here :

```
'this starts this block of code, it ask for 2 parameters sender and e each one with
'their respective types for example e as eventargs, handles means that this
'routine is fired when button12 is clicked
Private Sub Button12_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Button12.Click

    'here you are declaring an instance of type integer that will take the value of 0
    Dim points As Integer = 0

    'IsNumeric is a function that will return false/true if text property of label68 is numeric
    If IsNumeric(Label68.Text) Then
        ' if it is numeric you are converting the text property of label68 to integer and storing the value in points
        points = CInt(Label68.Text)
    End If

    'and if you undestood what I explained you should be able to read next lines
    If points = 0 Then
        ' if points=0 then you are saving "Draw" in your textbox191 text property
        TextBox191.Text = "Draw!"
    ElseIf points > 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Team 1!"
    ElseIf points < 0 Then
        TextBox191.Text = "Team 2!"
    End If
    'This is a button that shows the scorer the outcome of the cricket match and it is dependent on the totals of both the batting scores, the validation is shown above
End Sub
```